# Generating Random String in PL/SQL(oracle 9i) with restricted Letters

Tags: oracle, random, oracle9i

I'm trying to generate a Random String using PL/SQL with some restricted letters, because i want to avoid letters like O, o, 0, etc. I heard that this task can be achievable using the listagg function available in oracle 11g. But i want to achieve this using Oracle 9i as we are using this in our environment. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the desired string length?

Comment: the desired length can be from 10 to 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riffing off A.B.Cade's answer (it's getting a bit too far away from the original to keep in comments):

```
select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval()
from
(
  select distinct first_value(ch) over (partition by lower(ch)) as ch
  from (
    select substr('abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789',
        level, 1) as ch
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 59
    order by dbms_random.value
  )
  where rownum <= dbms_random.value(10,13)
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11968)

The inner select is putting each character in the string of values into a random order; the next level uses `first_value()` and `distinct` to pick whichever it sees first of an uppercase and lowercase pair (`a`/`A`) so you don't get repetition even ignoring case; that's then restricted to the first 10, 11 or 12 (distinct) rows; and finally it uses the same `xmlagg` call to turn those rows into a single string.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your valuable time and response. I got what i need for the day....

Answer (score 3):

Try using [DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996825) package to generate random strings.

Ex : `dbms_random.string('x',10)` gives uppercase alphanumeric character string of length 10.

But you cant exclude specific characters. You will have to use `TRANSLATE` or `REPLACE` functions to remove the unwanted characters.

Comment: +1: This seems by far the most simple method -- generate an overlong set of random characters and simply replace the undesirable ones. I don't know why anyone would bother with exotic solutions.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - but to use mixed-case and numbers you need to user `p` and then have to exclude non-alphanumeric characters as well (e.g. [with regex_replace](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11977)). Which is OK-ish for the original requirements, except you still have to list the allowed characters, but doesn't deal with the late-breaking no-duplicate part. (I'm not saying the requirements are sensible... *8-)

Comment: ... and nor for that matter is the Oracle version.

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches would be creating a user-defined aggregate function that mimic `listagg` function's behavior. Here is an example:

1. Our user-defined aggregate function:

   ```
    SQL> create or replace type stragg as object (
      2  
      3      str  varchar2(4000),
      4  
      5      static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  in out stragg)
      6                      return number,
      7  
      8      member function ODCIAggregateIterate   (self  in out stragg,
      9                                              value in varchar2 )
     10                      return number,
     11  
     12      member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self         in     stragg   ,
     13                                              return_value    out varchar2,
     14                                              flags        in number      )
     15                      return number,
     16  
     17      member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out stragg,
     18                                         ctx2 in stragg    )
     19                      return number
     20  )
     21  /

     Type created

     SQL> create or replace type body stragg is
      2  
      3      static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out stragg)
      4          return number is
      5      begin
      6          sctx := stragg(null);
      7          return ODCIConst.Success;
      8      end;
      9  
     10      member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
     11        self in out stragg, value in varchar2)
     12          return number is
     13      begin
     14          str := str || value;
     15          return ODCIConst.Success;
     16      end;
     17  
     18      member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in stragg,
     19          return_value out varchar2, flags in number) return number is
     20      begin
     21          return_value := str;
     22          return ODCIConst.Success;
     23      end;
     24  
     25      member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out stragg,
     26          ctx2 in stragg) return number is
     27      begin
     28          str := str || ctx2.str;
     29          return ODCIConst.Success;
     30      end;
     31  end;
     32  /

     Type body created

     SQL> create or replace function str_agg (input varchar2) return varchar2
       2      parallel_enable aggregate using stragg;
       3  /

     Function created
   ```

If you plan to work with strings that are more then 4000 in length you can use `CLOB` datatype instead of `varchar2`. Now, you can create an additional function that will generate a random string for you using that `str_agg` aggregate function. As you want to exclude some characters from the resulting string, I think it would be better to provide a set of characters from which the desired string will be generated.

```
SQL> create or replace function Str_gen(p_CharSet varchar2, p_length number)
  2  return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_res_str varchar2(4000);
  5  begin
  6   select str_agg(symbol)
  7     into l_res_str
  8     from ( select substr(p_CharSet, 
  9                          dbms_random.value(1, length(p_charset)), 1) as symbol
 10              from dual
 11           connect by level <= p_length
 12           order by dbms_random.value
 13           );
 14  
 15   return l_res_str;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created
```

And here is how it works:

```
SQL> select str_gen('abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789',11) as res
  2    from dual
  3  connect by level <= 11
  4  /

RES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NBG5jK6G46G
fSrzmyq7ZLE
vdGE1dRXlah
1D2IsI54qzD
PhktBAh5rXu
JtRsarxFNiV
1sUGFpwmypQ
7giwfdV4I7s
I2WMhKzxvc2
NZpngmrq1gM
rFuZ8gSUDgL

11 rows selected
```

Comment: nice solution. But this returns strings with characters from the input string only up to the specified length. In the example, the length is 11 and thus the output strings have characters only from a to k. How about replacing the `level` in the query `substr(p_CharSet, level, 1)` to a random number?

Comment: @Noel `How about replacing the level in the query substr(p_CharSet, level, 1) to a random number?`. Yes, it would be better to do so.

Comment: Nicholas the above approach is generating Random Strings in Upper case alone. I want to generate a string containing a combination of Upper case, lower case and numbers. Any Idea???

Comment: @DevakumarMahadevan To be able to generate strings in mixed case,  you can expand source character set by adding uppercase letters. For instance: `abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789`

Comment: Nicholas some letters are repeating again and again even to generate a String with the length of 8. How to avoid repetitions in a String??

Comment: Eliminating repeated letters means your string is no longer truly random.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function str_gen
( len in number)
return varchar2
as 
  str varchar2(4000);
  valid_chars constant varchar2(50) := 'abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz';  
begin
  for i in 1..len
  loop
    str := str || substr( valid_chars, dbms_random.value(1, length(valid_chars)), 1);
  end loop;
  return str;
end;
/
```

---

Without directly repeating  of the same letters

```
create or replace function str_gen
( len in number)
return varchar2
as 
  str varchar2(4000);
  valid_chars constant varchar2(50) := 'abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz';  
  last_char varchar2(1);
  new_char  varchar2(1);
  chars_len       NUMBER;
  num             NUMBER;
begin
  chars_len := length(valid_chars);
  num := 0;
  if len > 0 then
    loop      
      new_char := substr( valid_chars, dbms_random.value(1, chars_len ), 1);

      if num = 0 then 
        str := new_char;
        num := num +1;
      elsif new_char != last_char
      then 
        str := str || new_char;
        num := num +1;
      end if;
      last_char := new_char;
      exit when num = len;
    end loop;
  end if;
  return str;
end;
/


select str_gen(11) from dual;
```

Comment: How can i generate a string without a particular letter to be repeated again and again?